# JS error with nodejs_watchdog and chatroom module

Tags: distributions

I am trying to run [chatroom](https://www.drupal.org/project/chatroom) and nodejs_watchdog module with OpenAtrium. Nodejs seems to be working fine but in OpenAtrium pages its throwing JS errors, as below.

> nodejs_watchdog JS error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'callbacks' of undefined(anonymous function) @
>   nodejs.watchdog.js?o2oo29:4(anonymous function) @
>   nodejs.watchdog.js?o2oo29:12
>
> chatroom JS error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'connectionSetupHandlers' of undefined(anonymous function) @
>   chatroom.js?o2oswh:78(anonymous function) @ chatroom.js?o2oswh:191

I am not sure if this errors are due to nodejs or openatrium or jquery version conflict.